# Complemented Subspace Problem beyond Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

In the complementary subspace problem one asks for conditions on a locally convex vector space $E$ which guarantee that each closed subspace has a direct (topological) compliment in $E$.
This question was studied for Banach spaces, and Lindenstrauss showed that a Banach space has this property if and only if it is a Hilbert space.
Is there anything known for classes of LCVS beyond Banach spaces (e.g Frechet spaces, nuclear spaces) ?

Comment: For separable Frechet spaces, the questions is answered by Grothendieck (using Lindenstrauss' result). A separable Frechet space has "the complimented subspace property" if and only if it is either $\ell^{2}$, $\omega = (\mathbb{K})^{\mathbb{N}}$ or a product $\omega \ \times \ell^{2}$.